# based on radio button selection how to show/hide fields?

Tags: jquery

based on radio button selection how to show/hide fields in jquery?

```
<span class="m_h_checkbox_span">
    <input type="radio" id="resume_format" name="resume_format" alt="Docx" title="Docx" value="Docx">
    <div class="text">Docx</div>
</span>
<span class="m_h_checkbox_span">
    <input type="radio" id="resume_format" name="resume_format" alt="PDF" title="PDF" value="PDF">
    <div class="text">PDF</div>
</span>
<div class="case_form_filed" id="employee_name_row">
    <label for="employee_name">Employee Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" value="" class="text_box_case" name="employee_name" id="employee_name" onchange="textFieldOnChangeEvent(this,&quot;ed947c25f2064e3bb7a6449646744e5a&quot;,&quot;-1&quot;)">
</div>
```

Comment: Question is not very clear. What fields you want to hide? What did you try till now and what didn't work?

Comment: Can you post your javascript/jquery?  And what do you want it to do when they select an option?   Hide the others?  What if they mis-clicked or change their mind?

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in the code, let me clarify them first

1. You should not have multiple elements, with same ids, because it is not possible, To have radio group you can have same name but there ids should be different
2. It is not preferred to have DIV tag inside SPAN Tag, reason is SPAN is inline element, while DIV is box element(You can google this for more info)

You can write jQuery code for this

```
$('input[type=radio]').on("change", function(){
  if($(this).prop('id') == "resume_format") {
    $('element you want to hide').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You should use .prop() instead of .attr() after jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Bind change event on all radio button
    $("input:radio").change(function () {
        // Based on selected radio button value Show element
        if($('input:radio[name=resume_format]:checked').val() == "Your_check"){
            $('#Element_ID').show();
        }
   });
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues with your code and your question isn't very clear on what you want to hide.   But here is the best guess I could come up with.

Please see the fiddle for corrections to your code.   It had a lot of problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/brr7dkm6/

```
  (function($){
    $(function(){ 

        $('input:radio[name=resume_format]').change(function () {

            if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
                $("input:radio[name=resume_format]").not(':checked').each(function() {
                           $(this).parent().hide();
                           $(this).hide();

                });
            }

       });
    });
  })(jQuery);
```